# How to call common function in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node js. I need to create common function and pass in all router and also in view jade template. How could i do this.

Example: I have to check each every user login permission access for each menu.

Answer (score 1):

use a middlewares function that authenticates every request.

```
function middleware(req,res,next){
   if(req.session && req.session.user){
      next();
   }else{ 
      return res.json({
         response:"login"
      })
   }
}

route.get('/', middleware , function(){
      //rest of the code
});

route.post('/', middleware , function(){
      //rest of the code
});
```

use `res.render('page',{data:data});`to access data in .jade pages.

Comment: Thank you, This was useful. But how to pass parameters in middleware function.

Comment: How to display this middleware function in jade template.